# Stream live video from website to restream-server

Tags: html, nginx, html5-video, one-to-many

Many years ago, we built a live streaming application with Flash Media Server. Meanwhile, Flash got obsolete and we'd like to upgrade to a HTML5 solution.

Although I have found some answers, but they seem a bit old. Therefore, I wonder what is a good combo for video+audio live streaming nowadays (2017)?

The requirements are pretty simple: one broadcaster and many viewers (100+) that are using various modern browsers (IE11+, Edge, Firefox, Chrome). Ideally, we'd like to use a open-source solution.

On a server I'll use nginx-rtmp-module. But how can I stream from a browser to this server? **I don't want to use OBS or any other clients.** I need to stream from a website.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the RTMP route altogether, it's only needed for legacy compatibility and isn't worth your time.

DASH is a popular way to distribute video from the server to clients, as you have some choices for codec and you can re-use existing HTTP CDNs traditionally built for static content.

HTTP Progressive, Web Socket, and WebRTC can also all be used for distributing content, but you have increased infrastructure and complexity costs as these aren't nearly as common.

For the ingest end, you can use WebRTC (difficult), but what I prefer to do is use straight up Web Socket.  Use the MediaDevices API and getUserMedia to capture the video, use the Media Recorder API to run it through the codec, send that data over a web socket to the server, and then transcode on the server to whatever codec and format you need, for whatever you need.